# Error when finding first empty row in database (Excel/VBA/Forms)

Tags: forms, excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to create a form using Excel and VBA.
I get an error saying "Run-time error `91:
Object Variable or With block variable not set` when I try to submit the form. When I debug the error is occurring at line 7 `iRow= ws.Cell...`
Any help is very much appreciated! Below is the code for clicking the OK button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.TextBox_Name.Value) = "" Then
Me.TextBox_Name.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please complete the form"
Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_Name.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_Desc.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.Frame_Group.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox_Location.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.Frame_Time.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.Frame_Life.Value

MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
'clear the data
Me.TextBox_Name.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_Desc.Value = ""
Me.Frame_Group.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox_Location.Value = ""
Me.Frame_Time.Value = ""
Me.Frame_Life.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_Name.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: `I get an error saying "Run-time error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set` Your answer lies [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: In other words are you sure the sheet isn't blank?

Comment: `iRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

replace your line with these code
Its works :)